# Injectivity parameter

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, monotone-functions

For a function $f:(-∞; 1]$ $\rightarrow$ ${R}$ $$f(x)=x^2+mx+1$$ Determine $m$ for which $f$ is injective(~stricly monotonous), without use of calculus.

Based on my attempts, I've already restrained the interval of $m$ to $[-2;+∞)$ or even
$$[\frac{1+ 17^{1/2}} {2};+∞)$$ though I' m unsure it is correct, and am confident it can be more rigorously restrained.

Comment: The graph of this function without a restricted domain is a parabola. You just want to ensure that the vertex of the parabola does *not* lie over any point in the interior of the restricted domain (the boundary is okay).

Comment: yes, I had acknowledged that before asking, though I was unsure that the condition stated by martini was sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$ 
  x^2 + mx + 1 = \left(x + \frac m2\right)^2 - \frac{m^2}4 + 1, $$
hence, $f$ attains its minimal value in $x = -\frac m2$. Therefore, $f$ is injective iff $-\frac m2\ge 1$, or $m \le -2$.